# Проблема с таблицами css

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт [ссылка тут.](http://karuso.kz/bid/city) Если посмотреть на таблицу, то можно увидеть, что цена почему то стоит на несколько пикселей выше чем другие столбцы. С чем это связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в колонке где цена есть лишний `<br>` который приподнимает цену.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrtboelu1n1sml2/trouble.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Уберите `<br>` в коде и будет Вам счастье :)